# Access a list index after introducing words using input

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x, list

I want to know why I cant access a list index. I have a list full of words(input) but then t try to acces for example: list[2] and I get an error.

```
words=[]
n =input().split()
words.append(n)
print (words])
```

Intput: Hi internet what up
Output: [['hello', 'internet', 'what', 'up']]

```
print(words[0])
```

Output:['hello', 'internet', 'what', 'up']

```
print(words[1])
```

Output: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: lol, not a duplicate; one would have to already know the difference (not to mention the very existence of `extend`) in order to not run into this bug

Comment: Fundamental misunderstanding: "I have a list full of words(input)". You do not. You have a list, which *contains a single element*, which happens to be another list, which contains the word strings.

Answer (score 2):

use `extend` not `append`; `append` appends a single element whereas `extend` appends all elemnets of a given list

Comment: Thank you very much!! Do you know how to extend words in a list separated by " " but with a for, so let say-> for i in range 2: list.extend(input)
input=hey what up
output=[hey,what]

Comment: @AlejandroAlcarazGonzalez you don't. `.extend` avoids a for loop, but you could always do `for word in input().split(): words.append(word)`

Comment: @AlejandroAlcarazGonzalez words separated by `" "` are NOT A LIST! they are one single string. when you call `split()` the one single string is broken into many strings based on the `" "` separator. So, that's when you have a list of words and all the `" "` have been removed. In your question, you do not need 4 lines. You just need 1 line: `words = input().split()` and may be another line `print(words)` or `print(words[1])` depending on what you want to do. You only need extend if you need to read ANOTHER INPUT, then you do: `words.extend(input().split())` Lists and strings are DIFFERENT.